# Trouble with Javascript object syntax

Tags: javascript, oop, syntax

I have clearly got this wrong (because it doesn't work) but I thought the following two code blocks where functional identical, but one is working as expected, the other is not.

**Working:**

```
mfObject.questions = {}
mfObject.questions.active = "#"+$('.ui-page-active').attr('id');
```

***Not*** Working:

```
mfObject.questions = {
    active : "#"+$('.ui-page-active').attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Don't put a semi-colon at the end of your value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have a `;` at the end of the property assignment.

```
mfObject.questions = {
    active : "#"+$('.ui-page-active').attr('id') // <-- no semicolon here
}
```

Properties assigned inside an object literal are separated by commas if there are multiple assignments, and semicolons would never appear as terminators to a property assignment (though they may be present internally if you assigned a function to a property).

```
// Correct property assignment in an object literal
mfObject.questions = {
  active: "someval",
  prop1: "someval1",
  prop2: "someval2",
  prop3: function() {
    console.log("I have semicolon terminators in a function");
    console.log("because I have multiple statements");
  },
  prop4: "someval4"
};
```